# How to make a collection view similar to the Apple News App?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create an app that is similar to the layout in the Apple News app on iOS 10. There are different sections like `Top Stories`, `For you`, etc. I have placed a pic of the `For You` Section below:

[image]
[image]

The layout above has one big article on the top (the 12 billion gallons of water article) and then 2 horizontal articles (Ron howard and google cloud) and finally two vertical articles (philando castile and Daniel Day-lewis).

My question is how would one go about achieving this? What I am thinking is that you have multiple sections in a `UICollectionView` (a section for `For you`, `Technology`, `Politics`, etc) and each section has one main UICollectionView Cell. Then inside that main cell you have an additional 3 different cells (one for the big article, one for the vertical articles, and one for the horizontal articles). Is this a good way to achieve this? Like creating this many cells for one `UICollectionView`?

Comment: You need to build a custom flow layout for your collection view. Then you can essentially build any style you like without the need to nest collection view cells. You can find many examples online, just search for custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: @BJHStudios Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for. I'll take a look at it soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionFlowLayout` to layout anything you want.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/lighthola/MySwiftPractice/tree/master/AppleNewsApp) I made it just now.

Hope this can help.[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you so much this is perfect. I was just curious in `ViewController.swift` I do not see anywhere where you set the custom flowlayout to the collection view. More specifically this property: `@IBOutlet weak var flowLayout: AppleNewsFlowLayout! { ... }`

Comment: `AppleNewsFlowLayout` is set on `collectionView of StoryBoard`,  you can check at `Attributes Inspector`.

Comment: You can see the `AppleNewsFlowLayout` entity (the yellow cube) at `Document Outline` after you add a layout class to collection view.